# Rotating axis name in bokeh

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I have a graph as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMdWC.jpg). I want to year and month in from a graph  to make them more visible. How to do it in bokeh?

Answer (score 0):

As of version `0.12.15` this is [still an open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7643) and is not possible. This feature is planned to be implemented for the next release.